# MYSQL remote access works for one user, not another

Tags: mysql

After hours of trial and error and reading every post I can find on this topic, I can't get this to work.

I want to add a read-only remote user. My r/w user already works.

I have , basically:

```
Host   User    Password  SelectPriv  InsertPriv ...
%       RW       x          Y           Y       ...
%       RO       y          Y           N       ...
```

I also checked they have the same GRANTS (except user RO only has SELECT)..

then I issued the flush privs command , and it completed.

I go to the remote node, user RW logs in. everything is fine, with `mysql -h host -uRW -p`

Then I use the exact same command , except change RW to RO. I get the same password prompt, enter the password I used to create the user, and it says ACCESS DENIED for user....

I have a local version of "RO" with the same password. I confirmed in the Password col, they match.

It logs in and authenticates fine, on the local box. On the remote, access denied..

I also went to /var/log and tailed each of the most recently changed logs. None seem to have entries added for this failure.

Suggestions please!

Comment: Verify there are no other rows with User=RO (with a different value of Host) in the mysql.user table. also, what is the *exact* full reported error message ... "
denied for user 'foo'@'bar' Using password: yes"

Answer (score 0):

Both the RO, and the RW users DO have another row - each has "localhost" in the "Host" column...

(the actual hostname is changed on the error message)

The exact error is:

> Error 1045: (28000): Access denied for user 'RO'@'remote.com' (using password: YES)

TYVM for assisting.

I ran another test which seems a bit odd. I set up a new user with Host='%'. I get the same error trying to log in remotely. But I CAN log into that account on the local host. Even though it has no localhost row.

Does that seem right? I thought % host was for all EXCEPT the localhost?

Just wrote a Perl script. I CAN connect from the remote host with the Perl DBI to the RO user.

THIS is too WEIRD!

Comment: Please update the original question, rather than adding not-answers.

Answer (score 0):

... THINGS that make you go hmmm.

For now I'm connecting with the PRIVed user since the RO one won't work. Not great but it is what it is....